# Exist statement if value exists then do return other values

Tags: mysql

Attempting to use this code

```
AND (EXISTS (SELECT '1' FROM AMRPUSR
         WHERE AMRPUSR_USRC_CODE = 'BKGROUND'
         AND AMRPUSR_USRC_CODE <> 'BUSDESC'
         AND AMRPUSR_USRC_CODE <> 'EMPHIS'
         AND AMRPUSR_USRC_CODE <> 'FAMINFO'
         AND AMRPUSR_USRC_CODE <> 'GIFTOTHR'
         AND AMRPUSR_USRC_CODE <> 'PERSAFFIL'
         AND AMRPUSR_USRC_CODE <> 'PROFAFFIL'))
```

I'm trying to say if the value `'BKGROUND'` exists then do not show me the other values listed below it, 
but if `'BKGROUND'` doesn't exist then list everything below it...

any help?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want is a case statement.

```
SELECT
    CASE
       WHEN AMRP_USRC_CODE!='BACKGROUND THEN AMRP_USR_USRC_CODE
    END AS AMRP_USR_USRC_CODE,
    ...
FROM *YOUR_TABLE*;
```

Comment: CAN YOU BE MORE DESCRIPTIVE?

Comment: Which part are you having issues with? The basic idea is to use a case statement for each value you wish to have listed.  Does this not give you the desired result? Is there an error you are getting trying to implement it?